# Elasticsearch multiple analyzer on field

Tags: elasticsearch

Can i add multiple analyzer at the same field, eg.:

```
PUT my_index 
{
  "mappings": {
    "user": { 
      "properties": { 
        "title":    { 
           "type": "string", 
           "analyzer" : "italian, my_custom_analyzer" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely ["extend" an existing language analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#_reimplementing_language_analyzers) (such as italian)  in order to add some custom behavior.

There's an example [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#italian-analyzer)